# How to extract success and error responses from controllers

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating rest api's using nodejs, mongodb and express. And in each success response and error response I am sending those responses in a custom format. But that format is repetitive and in each if else and try catch block I am repeating that over and over again, and controller became noise and unreadable.

I want to separate/extract that logic somewhere central, like in future if I need to make any change to that format, I don't need to modify in multiple places. Please find the login function below.

**Auth Controller - **

```
    var api_var = {
      version: process.env.API_VERSION,
      developer: process.env.API_DEVELOPER
    };


    exports.login = async (req, res) => {
      var response_status = {};
      var response_dataset = {};
      var response_data = {};

      const errors = validationResult(req);

      try {
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
          const errorVal = errors.array();
          response_dataset = errors.array();
          response_status.message = errorVal[0].msg;
          response_data.dataset = response_dataset;
          (response_data.status = response_status), (response_data.publish = api_var);

          res.status(process.env.HTTP_RESPONSE_BAD_REQUEST);
          res.send({ response: response_data });
        } else {
          let { email, password } = req.body;
          let user = await User.findOne({ email });

          if(!user){
            response_status.message = "There is no user associated with this email address!";
            response_data.dataset = response_dataset;
            (response_data.status = response_status),
            (response_data.publish = api_var);

            res.status(process.env.HTTP_RESPONSE_UNAUTHORIZED);
            res.send({ response: response_data });
          } else if (user.status == 'inactive'){
            response_status.message = "Your Account is either disabled or removed!";
            response_data.dataset = response_dataset;
            (response_data.status = response_status),
            (response_data.publish = api_var);

            res.status(process.env.HTTP_RESPONSE_UNAUTHORIZED);
            res.send({ response: response_data });
          } else if(!global.Helpers.comparePassword(password, user.password)){
            response_status.message = "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password!";
            response_data.dataset = response_dataset;
            (response_data.status = response_status),
            (response_data.publish = api_var);

            res.status(process.env.HTTP_RESPONSE_UNAUTHORIZED);
            res.send({ response: response_data });
          }else if(user.isVerified == false){
            response_status.message = "Your Account is not varified. Please verify your Account!";
            response_data.dataset = response_dataset;
            (response_data.status = response_status),
            (response_data.publish = api_var);

            res.status(process.env.HTTP_RESPONSE_UNAUTHORIZED);
            res.send({ response: response_data });
          } else {
            let userDetails = {
              id: user._id,
              email: user.email,
              name: user.name,
              role: user.role
            };
            let Token = global.Helpers.createToken(userDetails);
            user_details = {
              token : Token,
              user : {
                role: user.role,
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                _id: user._id
              }
            }
            response_status.message = "Well Done, You Successfully Logged In to pawsticks!";
            response_data.dataset = user_details;
            (response_data.status = response_status),
            (response_data.publish = api_var);

            res.status(process.env.HTTP_RESPONSE_OK);
            res.send({ response: response_data });
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        response_dataset = error;
        response_status.message = error.message;
        response_data.dataset = response_dataset;
        (response_data.status = response_status), (response_data.publish = api_var);

        res.status(process.env.HTTP_RESPONSE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        res.send({ response: response_data });
      }
    }
```

In my current implementation that api_var object and response_status, response_dataset, response_data are repetitive. How can i be able to clean this mess.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw a custom error and catch in Error middleware, from there you can return same logic. error response.

Basic sample

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
class ResponseError {
  constructor(status) {
    this.status = status;
  }
}
function resError(err, req, res, next) {
  if(err instanceof ResponseError) {
    // Logic here
    res.status(400).send('Logic break')
  }else {
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
  }
}
app.route("/book/:id").get(function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.id == 2) throw new ResponseError(400);
  console.log(req.params);
  res.send("Get a random book");
});

app.route("/user/:id").get(function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.id == 2) throw new ResponseError(400);
  console.log(req.params);
  res.send("USER");
});
app.use(resError)
app.listen(3000);
```

More info: 
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html